# Set multiple locales on one page

Tags: php

On a webpage that contains items in various languages, it would be desired to display different dates in different languages:

`jeudi, 15 octobre` next to `Donnerstag, 15. Oktober` - on the same page.

Ist that possible?

Comment: You could generate the two parts of the page in iframes, so that they show on the same page but are separate page loads as far as the server is concerned. Probably not an ideal solution, but it might be a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you switch the locale with `setlocale`, the set locale is being used for everything after that.

So you could create a custom function which will switch the locale just for the desired output and then switch back. The following should work:

```
function locDate($format, $locale, $time = null)
{
    $oldlocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "0"); // get the current locale
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

    $date = date($format, $time);

    setlocale(LC_ALL, $oldlocale);
    return $date;
}
```

Using this for localized dates is just an example. This approach works with everything that gives different output based on the current locale.

This also works if you're using gettext for string translation. You can temporarily switch the locale to output certain chunks of text in a different language (assuming that a translation exists in your catalog and the catalog is loaded).

Answer (score 7):

lxg's answer above is mostly correct, but it has a couple problems:

1. You must use `strftime()` instead of `date()`. This is because PHP's date() function ignores setlocale(). Note that strftime() uses a slightly different format.
2. The call to setlocale() is system dependent. On my system, `setlocale(LC_ALL, "0")` returns the string:

   `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C`

   You definitely don't want to pass that entire string back into setlocale(). The solution is to use `LC_TIME` instead of `LC_ALL`.

Corrected function looks like this:

```
function locDate($format, $locale, $time = null)
{
    $oldlocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, "0"); // get the current locale
    setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale);

    $date = strftime($format, $time);

    setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldlocale);
    return $date;
}
```

Comment: Nice one geofflee