# Switch Locales in TYPO3, "live", on one page

Tags: typo3, locale, typo3-6.2.x

On [Set multiple locales on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011041/set-multiple-locales-on-one-page) I was enlightened you can switch locales in php live, during one php call.

For example, like this:

```
    $locale_old = setlocale(LC_TIME, 0);
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_CH');
    // do something
    setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale_old);
```

What about TYPO3? I have different dates on one page that should be displayed in different languages according to the content element they're in.

As the locale that renders the date is set globally, it can't be done using these two TypoScript Settings:

```
config.locale_all = de_CH
config.locale_all = fr_CH
```

Is it possible at all - and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with `TypoScript`, because `TypoScript` is not executed line by line, but rather parsed into one configuration tree which is then passed to the `FrontendController` (technical the call order is the other way around, but do not try to get into the inner magics of TYPO3 here).

So you either need to define your own wrapper script that you can call at the needed places with `stdWrap` methods or you switch to `Fluid` templating and create a `viewhelper` that does the switching for you. Inside this `viewhelper` you can use code you mentioned in your question.

The `TypoScript` setting does the `setlocale()` globally. Of course you can switch it while you execute your own PHP code. That means you can switch the setting (even in the `FrontendController`) inside your `Controller` or in your `View`.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Actually, I'm already using tx_news for those parts. So I could create a VH 'setLocale' and call it in the news template, based on an option set in the TS of that Content Object. Nice, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that would be a clean way to go.

Comment: I've made that viewhelper like this https://github.com/ursbraem/customvhs/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/SwitchlocaleViewHelper.php and tried adding it as such: https://gist.github.com/ursbraem/b7817ab0a720626b03db - but that doesn't change the locale for the `format.date` VH that follows afterwards. So I'd have to use an own proprietary `format.date` VH for that, or do you see what I did wrong?

Comment: I would make it wrap around, but it should work the way you intend. Did you debug whether the viewhelper is called at all?

Comment: Yes it's called, I output the locale, it was set to de_CH, but the next fluid VH was still outputting dates in de_FR. I'll try the wrap!

Comment: It might be that the viewhelper uses the global variable date format (install tool) to set the date format. In that case you can either extend the viewhelper (or copy it) or you could alter the global variable too.

Comment: Much simpler: I had (copied from somewhere) `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'fr_CH');`while it had to be `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_CH');`. Found out when I added an own format.date viewhelper based on fluid's. Thank you for your support in finding out!

Comment: The current solution (ugly, as it will not store and reset the main locale automatically) is again at http://github.com/ursbraem/customvhs/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/… and http://gist.github.com/ursbraem/b7817ab0a720626b03db

Comment: You can easily make it wrap (which would be more clean) by rewriting your viewhelper to render the children between the ``setlocale()`` calls. An example how to do this: https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/4b90d5be8c09a145b7cb4a7868bf4b37f18012e0:/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Format/Nl2brViewHelper.php

Comment: How does the VH know that `@param string $value` is the wrapped content? Is it just a convention that if there's only one value it will check for the content of the wrap?

Comment: AFAIK this depends of being either the inline notation or the normal Fluid Syntax. The important part is the ``$this->buildRenderChildrenClosure()`` or ``$this->renderChildren`` (if you do not use the ``CompileableInterface``).